# QStringList.append() crash on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, crash, qstring

I am running into a really odd crash on OS X with Qt 4.8.6.

I have a very simple bit of code (which works just fine in our Windows and Linux builds):

```
QStringList list;
list << "test";
```

What I'm finding is that the append operation will crash at runtime with the following stack trace:

```
QBasicAtomicInt::ref() { asm volatile("lock\n" ... }
QString::QString(QString const&)
QString::QString(QString const&)
QList<QString>::node_copy(QList<QString>::Node*from, QList<QString>::Node*, QList<QString>::Node*)
QList<QString>::detach_helper_grow(int, int)
QList<QString>::append(QString const&)
QStringList::operator<<(QString const&)
```

Most other operations including the destructor for QStringList lead to similar crash.

I'm really at a loss of how to debug this further, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely more than a `QStringList` failure. The lowest level stack frame shows the crash is most likely happening in the `QBasicAtomicInt` class.

Comment: It does feel like it might have something to do with the implicit sharing and the ref counting. However, I also see that in the QString copy constructor the source string data appears to be null...

Comment: Recompile with the addresssanitizer enabled, run it again and see if it complains about a memory corruption.

Comment: Usually backtraces look like this when either the string appended or the stringlist have been deleted already or similar. Are those two lines above the whole code or is there more going on between QStringList declaration and the <<? Is QStringList a member variable or a local one?

Comment: Those two lines are it, taken from the simple unit test I made to see if it will crash on our build machines as well.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical case of the Qt library being built by a different compiler or linked by a different C++ library than the rest of your application. On OS X, the main culprit tends to be libstdc++ vs. libc++, which have incompatible string implementations, among other things.

Can you reproduce this with a trivial example?, e.g.:

qstringlist.pro:

`SOURCES        = qstringlist.cpp`

qstringlist.cpp:

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QStringList list;
  list << "test";
  std::cout << list.join(" ").toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

..then `qmake qstringlist.pro && make && ./qstringlist.app/Contents/MacOS/qstringlist`

To get around this, I typically build Qt myself, with carefully chosen build settings if I want to run on other systems.

Comment: Thanks kintel, I've thought that this might be a problem so I made sure that the Qt libs and our build are both linking against libstdc++ and both built with clang. I will try a simple project like you suggested to at least see if this is a general problem or something specific with our project.

Comment: oh, and another common problem is that you may have picked up another Qt library at runtime than the one you were building against. To verify: `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 ./qstringlist.app/Contents/MacOS/qstringlist`

Answer (score 0):

We finally tracked it down, turns out the Qt library we are linking against had modified the headers and our build system wasn't pulling them in correctly. I guess that's a lesson that its always best to trust but verify :)

Thanks for the help everyone!